# dplyr string as column reference

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there anyway to pass a string as column reference to a dplyr procedure?

Here is an example - with a grouped dataset and a simple function where I try to pass a string as reference to a column. Thanks!

```
machines <- data.frame(Date=c("1/31/2014", "1/31/2014", "2/28/2014", "2/28/2014", "3/31/2014", "3/31/2014"), 
            Model.Num=c("123", "456", "123", "456", "123", "456"), 
            Cost=c(200, 300, 250, 350, 300, 400))

my.fun <- function(data, colname){
    mutate(data, position=cumsum(as.name(colname)))
}

machines <- machines %>% group_by(Date, Model.Num)     
machines <- my.fun(machines, "Cost")
```

Comment: You should read the nse vignette (`vignette("nse", package="dplyr")`, it addresses exactly this situation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an option that uses `interp()` from the *lazyeval* package, which came with your *dplyr* install.  Inside your function(s), you'll need to use the standard evaluation version of the *dplyr* functions.  In this case that would be `mutate_()`.

Note that the new column `position` will be identical to the `Cost` column here because of how you've set up the grouping in `machines`.  The second call to `my_fun()` shows it working on a different set of grouping variables.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lazyeval)

my_fun <- function(data, col) {
    mutate_(data, position = interp(~ cumsum(x), x = as.name(col)))
}

my_fun(machines, "Cost")
#        Date Model.Num Cost position
# 1 1/31/2014       123  200      200
# 2 1/31/2014       456  300      300
# 3 2/28/2014       123  250      250
# 4 2/28/2014       456  350      350
# 5 3/31/2014       123  300      300
# 6 3/31/2014       456  400      400

## second example - different grouping
my_fun(group_by(machines, Model.Num), "Cost")
#        Date Model.Num Cost position
# 1 1/31/2014       123  200      200
# 2 1/31/2014       456  300      300
# 3 2/28/2014       123  250      450
# 4 2/28/2014       456  350      650
# 5 3/31/2014       123  300      750
# 6 3/31/2014       456  400     1050
```

Answer (score 1):

We can evaluate in standard evaluation without the use of `lazyeval` package. We can set some string as variable name by using `setNames`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

machines <- data.frame(
  Date = c("1/31/2014", "1/31/2014", "2/28/2014", "2/28/2014", "3/31/2014", "3/31/2014"), 
  Model.Num = c("123", "456", "123", "456", "123", "456"), 
  Cost = c(200, 300, 250, 350, 300, 400)
  )

my_fun <- function(data, col) {
  mutate_(data, .dots = setNames(paste0("cumsum(", col, ")"), "position"))
}

my_fun(machines %>% group_by(Date, Model.Num), "Cost")
# Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
# Groups: Date, Model.Num [6]
# 
# Date Model.Num  Cost position
# <fctr>    <fctr> <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1 1/31/2014       123   200      200
# 2 1/31/2014       456   300      300
# 3 2/28/2014       123   250      250
# 4 2/28/2014       456   350      350
# 5 3/31/2014       123   300      300
# 6 3/31/2014       456   400      400
my_fun(machines %>% group_by(Model.Num), "Cost")
# Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
# Groups: Model.Num [2]
# 
# Date Model.Num  Cost position
# <fctr>    <fctr> <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1 1/31/2014       123   200      200
# 2 1/31/2014       456   300      300
# 3 2/28/2014       123   250      450
# 4 2/28/2014       456   350      650
# 5 3/31/2014       123   300      750
# 6 3/31/2014       456   400     1050
```