# R dplyr filter for non-standard evaluation (NSE) ".dots is missing, with no default"

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, lazy-evaluation

I am hoping someone can help determine why I receive an error message when using lazy evaluation as part of a dplyr filter_ verb. The end goal is to pass arguments by reference using a function but I have narrowed the problem down outside of a function.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lazyeval)
library(data.table)

data_raw_dt <- data.table(
  R_dates = seq(from = as.Date("2015/8/31"), by = "1 day", length.out = 30),
  grp_region = sample(letters[1:4], 30, replace = TRUE),
  z_valuation = rnorm(30)
)

# Create some NAs
data_raw_dt$grp_region[data_raw_dt$grp_region == "d"] <- NA

dates = "R_dates"
group = "grp_region"
column = "z_valuation"
filter_criteria = interp(~(!is.na(var)), var = as.name(group))

data_raw_dt %>%
  filter_(filter_criteria)
```

But this gives the following error message:
"Error in lazyeval::common_env(.dots) : 
  argument ".dots" is missing, with no default"

In this case, I am not sure how to specify .dots and when I do it asks for a list. I have checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27975124/pass-arguments-to-dplyr-functions), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27994985/dplyr-string-as-column-reference), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26492280/non-standard-evaluation-nse-in-dplyrs-filter-pulling-data-from-mysql) and structured my code following these examples with no success.

Package version:
dplyr 0.4.2
lazyeval 0.1.10
data table 1.9.4

Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Please provide a minimal [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Leave off any code that's irrelevant to the error. If none of the variables are actually defined, we can't test the code to see what's wrong. Yry `filter_(.dots=list(filter_criteria))`?

Comment: Include what version of `dplyr` and `lazyeval` you are using from `sessionInfo()`

Comment: @MrFlick thank you, I provided more reproducible code and posted versions of packages. It turns out the problem goes away when I use a data.frame instead of a data.table. Adding data.table to this question. Let me know if I need to do anything else to improve the formatting of this question or it now needs to be deleted/modified since it's a data.table vs. data.frame question.

Comment: If I copy/paste the code above, I do not get any error (`lazyeval_0.1.10`, `dplyr_0.4.3`, `data.table_1.9.6`)

Comment: @MrFlick, thank you again for testing, I will upgrade my R and packages

Comment: That did the trick, updating dplyr to 0.4.3 fixed the problem! Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace with

```
filter_(.dots = filter_criteria)
```