# Dplyr: String on both sides of mutate function

Tags: r, dplyr

Given this dataframe:

`t1 <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3), y = c(2,3,4))`

I would like to get the output as in this function:

`t1 %>% mutate_('y' = 'y * 2')`

But in such a way that I can define the input somewhere else:

```
t2 <- 'y'
t3 <- 'y * 2'
t1 %>% mutate_(t2 = t3) # Should produce output as t1 %>% mutate_('y' = 'y * 2')
```

Thanks for your help!

Best,
Jan

Comment: There are lots of questions on SO addressing this topic: 
[dplyr string as column reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27994985/dplyr-string-as-column-reference)
[Programming with dplyr using string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44121728/programming-with-dplyr-using-string-as-input)
[Pass a string as variable name in dplyr::filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48219732/pass-a-string-as-variable-name-in-dplyrfilter)
[Using a string as an argument to mutate verb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49469982/r-using-a-string-as-an-argument-to-mutate-verb-in-dplyr)

Comment: See https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Answer (score 1):

This code reproduces the dataframe from the above question:

`t1 %>% dplyr::mutate_(.dots = setNames(t3, t2))`